# How to read sheet data of uploaded file with using sheetJS and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sheetjs

So the file uploaded is an excel file that sheetJS needs to read, otherwise it will show as {}.

```
app.post('/sendExcel', function(req, res) {
    let data = req.body;
    var workbook = sheetJS.read(data, {type: 'buffer'});
    console.log(workbook.Sheets['Sheet1); //prints... "{ A1: { t: 's', v: '[object Object]' }, '!ref': 'A1' }"
    let excel = workbook.Sheets['Sheet1']['A1']['v'][0]; //prints... "["
```

So I've tried various things including changing the type client side as I had problems with it being of type buffer. So now it works partially, but I still can't access the data in the sheet.

As an example, I used the file path instead here, and it's shown to work as normal.

```
app.get('/excel', function(err, res, data) {
    var wb = sheetJS.readFile("data.xlsx");
    let excel = wb.Sheets['Sheet1']['A1']['v'];
    console.log(excel); //this prints "vehicle", which is what is supposed to happen, not "[".
      res.send(excel)
});
```

I am supposed to get the excel data from the form upload. That's the issue. It is is now successful when sending to the db, but will not access the whole data. I believe I need to change it back to an array.

You can use:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(workbook);
```

But this will not run in app.js

Here is my other answer with client-side and server-side. It might be helpful to others.

[Javascript Read Excel file on server with SheetJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143546/javascript-read-excel-file-on-server-with-sheetjs/64332216#64332216)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file you're trying to upload

Comment: @KunalMukherjee hi kunal, I have just found a solution for this but thank you for commenting anyway! I was really stuck on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the file reader. Append the excel sheet to the form in the body normally.

Client side:

```
let excelInput = document.getElementById("fileToUpload"); 
//excelInput: this html element allows you to upload the excel sheet to it
let excelFile = excelInput.files[0];
  let form = new FormData();
  form.append("excel", excelFile);

  fetch('/sendExcel', {method: "POST", body: form})
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Then use formidable server side.

Server side:

```
const sheetJS  = require('xlsx');
const formidable = require('formidable');
app.post('/excel', function(req, res) {
let data = req.body;
const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files, next) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
      return;
    }

    var f = files[Object.keys(files)[0]];
    var workbook = sheetJS.readFile(f.path);
    res.send(workbook);

  });
});
```

So formidable has to be used otherwise it won't work. Then you can use sheetJS.readFile instead of sheetJS.read.